# css file won't load when opening my website

Tags: html, css, web

i tested it locally and it's worked but when i upload it to my web host, some of the css code is not fully loaded, only some of the code inside of it are loaded. what happen pls i need help. i already checked the path.

thank you :)

this is from the host
[image]

this is from the local file

[image: this is from the local file. all the thing is already done, just need to upload]

````
<html lang="id">
    <head>
        <title>Weebs Desu! official discord website</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what isn't shown.

Comment: Did you upload `style.css` in the same folder as this file?

Comment: yes i upluad the style.css in the same folder

Comment: What CSS elements aren't working exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide more data to give us some clue, but here is a thing.

Maybe because the version of your css is not updated in the hosting yet. You already change your css code but the result still same as before. The solution for this is you can add some `v?=1.10` behind `style.css`.

So the result will be `style.css?v=1.10`, so the browser wont load the older version of css.

The number `?v=1.01` can be anynumber as long as greater than before (It works like patch).

Comment: hello sorry, but it worked!! THX SO MUCHHHHHH. btw so the `?v=1.10` worked like version of my own code?

Comment: Glad it work! No, you basically can put any number in there as long as it's changes from the prev version. The new css wont load because the cookie in the browser or something like that. Try with another browser and you'll good to go

Comment: This has nothing to do with cookies, this is the default caching mechanism of the browser. It saves bandwith by only loading new ressources. Everything it already fetched before it won't automatically redownload again unless you tell the browser to do so (like with this trick)

Answer (score 1):

Mine was not loading any of my CSS file and JS file, I used Chrome developer tool to troubleshoot and understand where the problem was.
Check the image below
[image]

I later realized that there were missing files in folders 'css' and 'js' with file names 'styles.css' and 'scripts.js' respectively.

Always countercheck the local files with the uploaded files. There might be a missing file.

Comment: Did you hear of snipping tools? Windows https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/8-easy-ways-to-take-screenshots-in-windows-10-and-11/ or Mac https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/taking-a-screenshot-on-mac-4-simple-ways-to-do-it/

Answer (score 0):

If it's working locally but not on your web host, your `style.css` filename casing might not be matching what you have in your `<link>` tag.

For example `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` should mean that your filename casing should also be `style.css`. Not `Style.css`.

Also hard to debug without a live example provided btw!

Comment: It wasn't updated at the time I answered it whoops! Glad you got it resolved. It was tricky because I can't post comments on the question yet.